# Given that $f$ and $g$ are Lebesgue measurable functions, show that $\{x|f(x)>g(x)\}$ is a measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was wondering how to prove this. So far, I've thought about defining a set $G_\alpha=\{x|g(x)>\alpha\}$, which we know is measurable for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and a set $E_\alpha=\{x|f(x)>g(x)>\alpha\}=E\cap G_\alpha$, where $E=\{x|f(x)>g(x)\}$, the set we want to prove is measurable. Then $E=\lim\limits_{\alpha\to-\infty}E_\alpha=\lim\limits_{\alpha\to-\infty}E\cap G_\alpha$ , and this is  a subset of a measurable set so it is measurable, but I'm not sure if that last statement is valid or if I'm on the right track.

Comment: **Hint:** $f-g$ is measurable

Comment: @Omnomnomnom why not turn that into an answer?

Comment: @CameronWilliams fair point I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $f-g$ is itself a measurable function.

Comment: Isn't that assuming what this is trying to prove?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews depends on how the textbook does things, I suppose

Comment: So the argument would be that $f-g$ is measurable, hence $\{x|f(x)-g(x)>\alpha\}$ for all real $\alpha$ is measurable. Then if we take $\alpha=0$, we have proven what we wanted?

Comment: Yep! That is, as long as we know that $f-g$ is measurable.  Usually, there'll be a theorem in the text to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\bigcup_{r\in \mathbb{Q}} \{x: g(x)<r\}\cap \{x: r<f(x)\}$ and $Y=\{x: g(x)<f(x)\}$. Then show that $X=Y$. Then $X$ is the countable union of measurable sets, so it is measurable, and it holds.

Comment: Thanks. This was a helpful response too.